# Jquery Mobile : float several buttons right, in the header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile and I am trying to place two button on the right of the header.

```
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Myapptitle</h1>
            <div class="share-it-wrapper">
                <select name="select-choice-share" id="select-choice-share" class="shareitbutton" data-icon="app-shareicon" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="notext" onchange="handleSocialShare()">
                    <option value="no"></option>
                    <option value="facebook"><img src="images/fb.png" />Facebook</option>
                    <option value="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" />Tweeter</option>
                    <option value="email"><img src="images/email.png" />Email</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        <a href="#creditspage" data-icon="info" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Credits</a>
        </header>
```

For now, my buttons are not aligned :
[image]

The [doc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html) indicate to use `data-role="controlgroup" and data-type="horizontal"` but if I wrap the buttons into a `<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">` then the #creditspage buttons becomes text... is there a bug in JQM (Cf the doc seems to also have the problem). How can I achieve perfect alignment for buttons on the right ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround both buttons in a div with class `ui-btn-right`. This places the div at the right side of the header.  Then you need a little CSS to put the 2 buttons inline and next to eachother.

```
<header data-role="header">
     <h1>Myapptitle</h1>

    <div class="ui-btn-right">
        <div class="share-it-wrapper">
            <select name="select-choice-share" id="select-choice-share" class="shareitbutton" data-icon="app-shareicon" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="notext" onchange="handleSocialShare()">
                <option value="no"></option>
                <option value="facebook">
                    <img src="images/fb.png" />Facebook</option>
                <option value="twitter">
                    <img src="images/twitter.png" />Tweeter</option>
                <option value="email">
                    <img src="images/email.png" />Email</option>
            </select>
        </div> 
        <a href="#creditspage" data-icon="info" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button" class="headerButton">Credits</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

The CSS to make this work is a little different in jQM 1.3 vs 1.4.

For 1.3:

```
.headerButton, .share-it-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px!important;
}
.headerButton {
    margin-top: 8px!important;
}
```

For 1.4:

```
.headerButton, .share-it-wrapper {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px!important;
}
.share-it-wrapper .ui-select{
    display: inline;    
}
```

> 1.3 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8qf9P/1/)**
>
> 1.4 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LAMwD/)**

Comment: Thanks man ! I just had to tune the css a bit, but it works fine.

Comment: Hi @ezanker sorry to bother you again with this question but the solution doesn't work on Chrome for Android. The share button goes to the left, see here : http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/191/zrw0.png  Can you help me figure out why (I don't have webinspector because Weinre doesn't work for CHrome Android).

Comment: @Louis, I opened both fiddles on my Nexus7 Android 4.4 Chrome and everything looks fine... That is the only Android device I have access to. You may want to make a new question with a fiddle of your actual code that reproduces this and specify which devices/versions exhibit the problem